# submitting PySpark app to spark on YARN in cluster mode

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to test a big data platform that has been built for the team I work in. It has spark running on YARN.

Is it possible to create PySpark apps and submit them on a YARN cluster ?

I'm able to submit an example SparkPi jar file successfully, it returns the output in the YARN stdout logs.

Here is my PySpark code that I'm trying to test;

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

HDFS_MASTER = 'hadoop-master'

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn')
conf.setAppName('spark-test')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

distFile = sc.textFile('hdfs://{0}:9000/tmp/test/test.csv'.format(HDFS_MASTER))

nonempty_lines = distFile.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)
print ('Nonempty lines', nonempty_lines.count())
```

The command I try at my CMD in the spark directory:

```
bin\spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 4g
executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 1 examples\sparktest2.py 10
```

My script is called `sparktest2.py` in my examples directory in my spark directory.

Logs (stderr):

```
 application from cluster with 3 NodeManagers
 17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
 17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
 17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
 17/03/22 15:18:39 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
 java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SPARK_HOME
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$findPySparkArchives$2.apply(Client.scala:1148)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$findPySparkArchives$2.apply(Client.scala:1147)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.findPySparkArchives(Client.scala:1147)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:829)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:240)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.9.24:42155
17/03/22 15:18:39 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/03/22 15:18:39 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/03/22 15:18:39 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1
17/03/22 15:18:39 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 1, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
17/03/22 15:18:47 ERROR ApplicationMaster: SparkContext did not initialize after waiting for 100000 ms. Please check earlier log output for errors. Failing the application.
17/03/22 15:18:47 INFO ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User application exited with status 1)
17/03/22 15:18:47 INFO ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://hadoop-master.overlaynet:9000/user/ahmeds/.sparkStaging/application_1489001113497_0038
17/03/22 15:18:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/03/22 15:18:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/ahmeds/appcache/application_1489001113497_0038/spark-1b4d971c-4448-4a5f-b917-3b6e2d31bb95
```

Errors from stdout:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sparktest2.py", line 16, in <module>
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
File "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local dir/usercache/ahmeds/appcache/application_1489001113497_0038/container_1489001113497_0038_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
File "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/ahmeds/appcache/application_1489001113497_0038/container_1489001113497_0038_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 168, in _do_init
File "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/ahmeds/appcache/application_1489001113497_0038/container_1489001113497_0038_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 233, in _initialize_context
File "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/ahmeds/appcache/application_1489001113497_0038/container_1489001113497_0038_02_000001/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
File "/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/ahmeds/appcache/application_1489001113497_0038/container_1489001113497_0038_02_000001/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SPARK_HOME
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$findPySparkArchives$2.apply(Client.scala:1148)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$findPySparkArchives$2.apply(Client.scala:1147)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.findPySparkArchives(Client.scala:1147)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:829)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:240)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems to be complaining about `SPARK_HOME`, which I have setup in my environmental variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Python version 3.5
Spark Version 2.0.1
OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that made it work for me was adding the following at my cmd;

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/dev/null
--conf spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME=/dev/null
--files pythonscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the similar issue. set "SPARK_HOME" in hadoop-env.sh and restart ResourceManager, NameNode, DataNode. It should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
./spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --queue default \
--num-executors 20 --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 3 \
--driver-memory 1G \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/dev/null \
--conf spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME=/dev/null \
--files  /home/user/script.py
```

Comment: Please, add a explanation (short) of the issue's causes, and explain your response.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made